# Media Queries stopped working in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

We still get a lot of traffic from ie8, but we are determined to go the responsive route. We've gotten media queries to work in ie8 in the past, but have not been successful with our newest template.

Our CSS/viewport setup in html head tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/request/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/request/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/request/css/styles.css">

<script src="http://www.oursite.com/js/modernizr.custom.2.6.2.js"></script>
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
      <script src="http://www.oursite.com/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Our media query syntax (using bootstrap):

```
@media (max-width: 767px) { }
```

I swear this has worked in the past, but now doesn't. We've tried various other polyfills with modernizr customizations, tried html5 shiv in place of modernizr, tried adjusting meta viewport settings, and tried different media query syntax (@media screen...). I've triple checked the html and it validates. We're using row-fluid from bootstrap - but it should be setup properly. I'm running out of ideas. Help?

Comment: Hi @Marc, just curious - why did CSS3 get removed from this question's title? Are media queries CSS3? or am I mistaken?

Comment: We try to avoid tags in titles. I know Media Queries is also a tag, but the title wouldn't make sense without. I thought CSS3 wasn't necessary in the title. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

i used bootstrap in a press site but it does not worked on IE8, i used css3-mediaqueries.js javascript but still not working. if you want your media query to work with this javascript file add screen to your media query line in css

here is an example :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>

<style>
     @media screen and (max-width:900px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:900px) and (max-width:1200px) {}
     @media screen and (min-width:1200px) {}
</style>
```